# Get hidden IvideoWindow Image

Tags: c#, c++, windows, delphi, directx

i need to get Image of hidden IvideoWindow ("ActiveMovie Window"), which shows webcam preview. As far as i can tell preview isn't overlay, it doesn't have overlay features, i can use printscreen on it, but i need window to stay hidden all the time, so that won't help. Also `PrintWindow()` api function returns me black screen.

Programming languages: c#, c, c++, java, pascal.

Operating system: Windows XP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the window caption, border etc. alright when you don't specify 'PW_CLIENTONLY' in nFlags with 'PrintWindow'?

Comment: Hi Sertaz, I tried with and without PW_CLIENTONLY still the same black screen.

Comment: I think I've made the incorrect assumption that 'IVideoWindow' would be a top-level window... Not all applications/windows process WM_PRINTCLIENT, take a look at the following article which subclasses a window (in/out of process) to make it handle the message. ( http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html ) But even if it works what will happen when you have an overlayed video, IMHO this is not the correct approach.. (BTW if you prepend '@' to the name of the person when you're replying to a comment, the person gets notified of your comment).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to show the window but outside the desktop. Set the left position at the desktop.width+1 (not screen.width, because users may have multiple screens) and then make it visible.

That way normal functions like printscreen work and users still won't see it.